# What's the difference between double jump and power jump in Cyberpunk 2077?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

I am wondering if I should get Reinforced Tendons (double jump) or the Fortified Ankles (power jump) and since they both are 45k I want to make an informed decision.

What is their respective benefits / downsides?

I assume the power jump is harder to control than a double jump. But does the power jump actually allow me to jump higher than the double jump? Are there certain regions that can only be accessed with a power or double jump or is it only a tradeoff between total height of the jump and its maneuverability?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the most part, this is going to come down to taste, and how the separate mechanics *feel* to you in play. The Power Jump does allow for slightly more altitude and distance, but in terms of accessing areas, I haven't found anything where I'm meaningfully cut off from access yet. Meanwhile, the double jump does offer a bit more control and reactivity - you can time it well to, for example, minimize fall damage, and use it to move around corners a bit more readily as well.

If you're interested in exploring the games... glitchier side, there are some wall-hack style shenanigans and otherwise inaccessible areas that double jump will allow you to reach, but power jump won't, by exploiting the abilities interaction with time-slow cyberware like the Kerenzikov.

Basically, it all comes down to which method you feel more comfortable using. Alternately, money is really pretty plentiful in CP77; buy one, try it out for a while, when you've got some spare cash, buy and try the other, and know you can always switch back and forth at your friendly neighborhood ripperdoc at no further cost.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't use Double-Jump to completely negate falling damage -- if you get into the terminal velocity animation, you lose the ability to trigger your double-jump. But for shorter distances, totally viable!

Comment: The minimize fall damage ability was the dealmaker for me to opt for the double jump.

Comment: @ravendreamer indeed. Hence, minimize, and not negate.